# XML file load QT not working

Tags: xml, qt, load

This xml read is not working at all and I don't get why. I'm not sure it properly creates the user object, but anyway I can't login any account after Database load.

Whenever I register a User account without closing the app, I can login so I guess it's not a login problem. XML save is working fine.

My database is a list of SmartUtente* objects.
A SmartUtente object is just a User*.

```
void Database::load(string p){
cout<<"Caricamento in corso..."<<endl;
try{
    if(p.empty()) return;
    if(!p.empty()) clean();
    QDomDocument doc("dbLinkedin");
    QFile file(QString::fromStdString(path));
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::WriteOnly)){
        cout<<"Errore: permessi insufficienti \n";
        throw Eccezioni::BadPermission();
    }
    int n = 0;
    El users = doc.firstChildElement("users").firstChildElement("user");
    while(!users.isNull()){
        El pointer;
        Utente * s;
        if(users.attributeNode("type").value() == "basic"){
            s= new UtenteBasic();
        }
        else if(users.attributeNode("type").value() == "business"){
            s= new UtenteBusiness();
        }
        else if(users.attributeNode("type").value() == "executive"){
            s= new UtenteBusiness();
        }
        s->setName((users.firstChildElement("name").text()).toStdString());
        s->setSurname((users.firstChildElement("surname").text()).toStdString());
        s->setUsername((users.firstChildElement("username").text()).toStdString());
        s->setPassword((users.firstChildElement("password").text()).toStdString());
        s->setSesso((users.firstChildElement("genre").text()).toStdString());
        s->setCity((users.firstChildElement("city").text()).toStdString());
        s->setEmail((users.firstChildElement("email").text()).toStdString());
        pointer= users.firstChildElement("qualifications").firstChildElement("qualific");
        while(!pointer.isNull()){
            s->setQualification((pointer.text()).toStdString());
            pointer= pointer.nextSiblingElement("qualification");
        }
        s->setBirth((users.firstChildElement("birth").text()).toStdString());
        pointer= users.firstChildElement("contacts").firstChildElement("contact");
        while(!pointer.isNull()){
            s->setRete((pointer.text()).toStdString());
            pointer= pointer.nextSiblingElement("contact");
        }
        SmartUtente* su= new SmartUtente(s);
        db.push_back(su);
        users= users.nextSiblingElement("user");
        n++;
    }
    cout<<"Termine caricamento"<<endl;
    setPath(p);
    cout<<"Path settato"<<endl;
    file.close();
}
catch(Eccezioni::BadPermission){
    QMessageBox::information(0,"Caricamento non riuscito","E' possibile che non si disponga più dei permessi necessari per leggere il database");
    return;
}
```

}

Comment: Just to clarify, and I suggest to add this also to the question: you create this SmartUtente wich I believe is an Xml obejct of some kind which you then  use to login to somewhere right ? The login does not work properly but you believe the problem is in this part of the code. correct ?

Comment: SmarUtente is just an Utente*
And my database is a list<SmartUtente*>

Comment: Two things: 1. You're creating and using a QDomDocument without loading any XML content into it. 2. QtXML is no longer maintained.  I wouldn't rely on it if I were you.

Comment: the XML file refers to QFile file(QString::fromStdString(path));

path is ./data.xml

Anyway this is a university project, so unluckily it's not a personal choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

Missing doc.setContent(&file);